# how to print white space character using string variable?

Tags: java, whitespace

if `String s="\t\n";`

then I want to print `s` and result will be : `"\t\n"` .

Example:

```
String s = "\t\n";
System.out.println(s);
```

> Output: \t\n

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You want to print "\t\n" or an indent and then a new line?

Comment: I want to print "\t\n" . not , an indent with new line

Comment: Do "\\t\\n" instead.

Comment: But, at first I have to check , s is a white space or not? If I use s = "\\n\\t" , then s is not a white space .

Comment: @FarhanRahmanArnob What is a "white space"?

Comment: Actually I want to make token like this, <WhiteSpace, “\n\t”> or <WhiteSpace, “\f\t”>  . For this, I am developing a Lexical Analyzer . But, cannot printing  "\n\t"

Comment: @immibis. Sorry , It will be whitespace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use `str.replace()`:

```
String s = "\n\t";
s = s.replace("\n", "\\n");
s = s.replace("\t", "\\t");
System.out.println(s);
```

> Output: \n\t

Comment: s is a variable . Then sometimes I will input "\t\n" , sometimes I may use '\f\t" . Then, what can I do?

Comment: You have to use `replace` for every escaped character you have

Comment: Thank you . This is I am looking .

Answer (score 0):

you can use `"\\n\\t"` to do so.Since `\n` is the new line character and `\t` is the tab. But if you need to print `\` you need to use `\\`

Comment: Just like in String literals ``\`` is also treated as special character in our post (since there are also some special characters here like `#` at start of line which may require escaping). Safest way to be sure it will be printed in a way you want is by surrounding your text in `code block`.